# getElementsByClassName and <a class="asdf" href="url.com">String</a>

Tags: javascript, href, getelementsbyclassname

I'd like to collect data from a webpage where there are a lot of lines like these?

```
<a class="asdf" href="http://url.com/jkl/0123/qwer">String</a>
```

From this line I need the numbers from the url (`0123`) and the `String`.
I could figure how to get the numbers, but I have problems with the `String`. I have this code, that collect the numbers in an array:

```
var titles = document.getElementsByClassName("link-title");
var ids=[];
var tmp;
var i;
for (i=0; i<titles.length; i++) {
    tmp=titles[i].toString().split("/");
    ids.push(tmp[4]);
}
```

Is it possible to get the `String`s from the `titles`? I'm completely dumb for javascript, though I learned java and a little xml and I could do in java, but the webpage has something DDoS protection, so I can't connect/download it.

Comment: `linkTitle = titles[i].innerText;` inside the `for` loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The things you get back from `getElementsByClassName()` are DOM nodes. The `.toString()` function won't be very useful, but the DOM APIs will let you get the attributes and the node contents:

```
for (i=0; i<titles.length; i++) {
    ids.push( titles[i].href );
}
```

That would extract the `href` attributes into your array. (You can still dot that `.split()` if you want pieces of the URLs of course.) If you wanted the text:

```
for (i=0; i<titles.length; i++) {
    ids.push( titles[i].textContent );
}
```

To be compatible with Internet Explorer, that'd be:

```
for (i=0; i<titles.length; i++) {
    ids.push( titles[i].textContent || titles[i].innerText );
}
```